# How to read collapsed UTF-8 string

Tags: json, swift, string, macos, encoding

I'm trying to read JSON from this address

> http://www.defense.gov/data.json'

But this data contains illegal character 0x92 in its 2771th line, so

```
try! String( contentsOf: URL( string: "http://www.defense.gov/data.json" )!, encoding: .utf8 )
```

crashes with exception below.

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The file “data.json” couldn’t be
>   opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)."
>   UserInfo={NSURL=http://www.defense.gov/data.json, NSStringEncoding=4}:
>   file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/

Is there any way to read JSON from this site without writing my own string reader ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the content, all characters other than that single 0x92 are in ASCII range (0x00...0x7F). So, you may try using encoding ISO-8859-1 (alias ISO-Latin-1), which maps all bytes to U+0000...U+00FF, so may not cause encoding issue.

```
var rawStr = try! String(contentsOf: URL(string: "http://www.defense.gov/data.json")!, encoding: .isoLatin1)
```

You can remove that character if needed.

```
rawStr = rawStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{92}", with: "")
```

And re-encode it as a valid UTF-8 data:

```
let dataUTF8 = rawStr.data(using: .utf8)!
```

Re-encoded data can be processed with `JSONSerialization`:

```
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataUTF8) as! [String: Any]
```

---

All codes above are written for experimental purpose. All `try!`, `as!` or forced unwrapping (`!`) are not safe here and you may need to handle them in more nil-safe manner in actual app. And `String(contentsOf:)` may consume indefinite time, especially in bad-communication environment. You should not call it in the main thread in actual app.

Comment: Thanks, replacing occurrence is pragmatic idea.